# SWIG Lua and passing arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, lua, swig

I currently have the following lua code:

```
    g = engine.CGeometry()

    vertexes = {}

    vertexes[1] = 0
    vertexes[2] = 0
    vertexes[3] = 0

    vertexes[4] = 0
    vertexes[5] = -1
    vertexes[6] = 0

    vertexes[7] = -1
    vertexes[8] = 0
    vertexes[9] = 0

    print "adding vertexes"
    g:SetVertexes(vertexes)
```

where g:SetVertexes() isimplemented in C++ as:

```
void CGeometry::SetVertexes(double* vertexes){
    this->vertexes = vertexes;
}
```

resulting in this error:

```
adding vertexes
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (Error in SetVertexes (arg 2), expected 'double *' got 'table')
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the datatype of vertexes?

Comment: for the moment I have sidestepped this problem by adding a SetVertex(int idx, double vertex)

Comment: I have a similar problem using Python. Tables (or lists in Python) don't convert to arrays with SWIG.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing:

```
void CGeometry::SetVertexes(double vertexes[]);
```

in the interface defintion.  Judging from the documentation, SWIG makes a difference between pointers and arrays.

Comment: at one point I changed double* vertexes to double vertexes[] and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can you carrays.i module as is described here: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html

For example you have such function in C++:

```
void fun(double arr[]) { }
```

Then you load module in .i file:

```
%include "carrays.i"
%array_functions(double, doubleArray);
void fun(double arr[]);
```

And in Lua script:

```
a = new_doubleArray(10)           # Create an array
doubleArray_setitem(a,0,5.0)      # Set value 5.0 on index 0
fun(a)                            # Pass to C
delete_doubleArray(a)             # Destroy array
```